# Tomcat's form based authentication with ajax app

Tags: ajax, tomcat, redirect, form-authentication, j-security-check

I use tomcat's form based authentication on a webapp which use most of the time ajax call.
The configuration of the realm is pretty well documented, and it's working.

My problem begin when the user's session is ended, for any reason.
The subsequent ajax call will have a 200 ok response, with the content being the login page.

I'm looking for a way to change the beavaior of tomcat, like sending a 401 instead of hiding the content, forcing a client redirect, or any other solution that let the JS script know that the session is over and authentication is required once again.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/index_tagsupp_13.html, I tried to add some custom header with http-equiv meta tag in my html login page.

But it doesn't work as expected. It seams that tomcat doesn't read static content in order to add headers.

I should also mention this post:
http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/9/Expiring-Session-via-AJAX-using-HTTP-Response-Headers

Answer (score 0):

What i end up doing is, on the js side, scan start of every response using a short regexp like this:

```
/^<!DOCTYPE html>/.test(responseBody)
```

It works, but take extra time for every request.
It only work because i know that i never use html as answer from the server.